# In bash, Loop and send commands to execute

Tags: linux, csv, pipe

Im trying to execute a program and send it commands based on a file that Im reading but as soon as I send the command the loop stop..it must be related to pipes but I would appreciate if someone could explain how they work

Code:

```
function setValue{

 echo "$1" > &9 
}

mkfifo program.fifo

./program
exec 9 > program.fifo

while read value
do 

setValue $value

done < file.csv
```

file.csv has 8000 rows, but the program stops after the first line...and finishes the execution without looping on any more lines of the csv

Comment: **<** `file.csv` surely?

Answer (score 0):

By leaving the pipe open for reading the loop is not finished after reading the first line and it can continue to the end of the file:

```
exec 9 <> program.fifo
```

Answer (score 0):

What is reading from `program.fifo`?  If there is no process that is reading it, then your script is blocked trying to write.  That write will not complete until some process is reading the fifo.

Comment: it is a parameter for a third party program, but i dont think the script is blocked. As the code is not waiting on the first row of the file, but it directly finishes the execution of the loop..and it finishes the code without reading any more from the file.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the code you aren't showing us in the while loop is consuming all of its stdin, which is the same as the input of the while loop.  The cleanest way to avoid that is to ensure that the commands in the loop are not reading from the same file as the loop.  There are many ways to do that; I like:

```
while read value; do {
   commands
} < /dev/null
done  < file.csv
```